# How to get value from multiple SQL table and show that in html/php table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, html-table

I have a SQL database named `result` having table `res` and `sub`. 
For example,
The `res` table column and contents are:

```
sno regno        name       sub1  sub2  sub3  sub4  sub5  

1   1DU12CS100   student1   70    80    85    70    90     
2   1DU12CS101   student2   75    70    90    80    70
3   1DU12EE015   student3   80    85    70    50    65
4   1DU14CS123   student4   88    85    85    90    70
5   1DU13ME050   student5   85    90    70    60    55
```

The `sub` table column and contents are:

```
Sno   batname     sub1      sub2       sub3       sub4       sub5

1     1DU12CS     Maths     English    Hindi      Urdu       Social 
2     1DU12ME     Sanksrit  Chinese    Japanese   French     Dutch
3     1DU12EE     Circuit   Electrical Electronic Maths      Hindi
4     1DU14CS     Hindi     Maths      Urdu       Science    Maths
5     1DU13ME     Computer  Maths      Electrical Mechanical GK
```

I want to fetch some value from table `res` and some from table `sub` and display in php/html table.

```
1DU12CS100  -- 
                                   1DU ->college code
                                   12 ->Student admission year
                                   CS ->computer science
                                   100->roll no of student
```

When someone enters 1DU12CS100 in php form, the result should be displayed like this...

```
Subjects    Marks

Maths       70
English     80
Hindi       85
Urdu        70
Social      90
```

And when someone enters 1DU13ME050, then the display should be

```
Subjects      Marks

Computer      85
Maths         90
Electrical    70
Mechanical    60
GK            55
```

The php form code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<body>

<form action="result.php" method="post">
Enter your Reg No: <input type="text" name="regno"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The result.php code is // What changes should be made in this php code ??

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myresult";
$password = "abcdefg";
$dbname = "myresult";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$regno = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['regno']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myresult WHERE regno LIKE '$regno'"; // What changes should be here ??
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$columns = array();
$resultset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (empty($columns)) {
        $columns = array_keys($row);
    }
    $resultset[] = $row;
}


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "{$row['sub1']}{$row['sub2']}"; // What changes should be made here??



// Print the data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach($row as $_column) {
        echo "{$_column}";
    }
}
    }
} else {
    echo "Result Not Found";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Using substrings of id is generally frowned on. Instead store a batname id and a student id separately. Much easier in Sook many ways.

Comment: exactly what Peter Bowers just said.  You can grab substrings, but you have to be absolutely certain that they are the ONLY place they exist.   I strongly suggest expanding the database and using that instead of relying on your `regno` field;   unless you are forced to (this looks like a remnant of old punch card style data management), I'd restructure your data.

Comment: "Normalization " is the term you should research on Google & find some articles or tutorials. Restructuring your database well is going to pay huge dividends in the future ... it only gets harder the longer you wait...

Comment: Thank you everyone for help. I am very new to PHP and SQL. What I have done is from searching on Google and Learning it from some websites...
What I want is you can see from here http://results.vtu.ac.in/vitavi.php and check by entering 1DS13CS001, 1NH13CS052, 1OX13CS001 etc..
1 is code for Bangalore region, Next 2 Letter is college code, Next 2 letter is year of admission, Next 2 is the branch/course code, Next 3 is Registration Number... You can check college code from here ... http://vtu.ac.in/affiliated-institutes/affiliated-institutes-bengaluru/

Comment: I don't know the best method to arrange database for that and fetch results from it... Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT sub.batname, sub.sub1 as subsub1, sub.sub2 as subsub2, ...,
        Res.sub1 as ressub1, ...
    FROM res 
    JOIN sub ON sub.batname = substr(res.regno, 1, 7)
    WHERE regno LIKE '$regno'";
```

(I haven't listed all the columns. Since you named the columns the same you have to specify aliases. Changing the names would be a good idea - subn isn't a great name. )

Then down below ...

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo "{$row['ressub1']}{$row['subsub1']}";
```

Comment: What I really wanted is fully understood by you and I was sure that your code will definitely fulfill my need but one problem arises is...The error I am getting from phpmyadmin SQL box is #1305 - FUNCTION akfashio_result.substr does not exist.

Even from result.php page I am getting... Result Not Found

Comment: copy/paste the exact query you tried in phpmyadmin into a comment here.

Comment: Sorry there was some mistake... Earlier I had executed subm.batname = submstr(res.regno, 0, 7) because my table name was subm so I thought it should be submstr but later I got to know that substr is an inbuilt function...

Comment: I have created a separate table sub and res ...Now I have executed... SELECT sub.batname, sub.sub1 AS subsub1, res.sub1 AS ressub1 FROM res JOIN sub ON sub.batname = substr( res.regno, 0, 7 ) WHERE regno LIKE '1DU12CS100'; But the result is MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 sec)

Comment: Ya I got.... sub.batname = substr( res.regno, 1, 7 )... It should be 1,7 not 0,7... I didn't know about the term substr hence I was thinking how can I do this... But when I knew that it is a function then I searched on google and found http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substr   and then I changed the code.... now it is working...

Comment: And Very Very Very Thank You for the help and for the code... I don't know whether there will come more problem in the project I am doing ... but for the current I need only this... If there will come any problem then I hope you will be there to help... Thank you again....!

Comment: hmm... I am not able to represent it in the form of * ... My code in php is $sql = "SELECT * FROM res JOIN sub ON sub.batname = substr( res.regno, 1, 7 ) WHERE regno = '$regno

What to print for sub table ?
I tried this but it is not printing anything 
echo "{$row['ressub1']}{$row['subsub1']}";
    echo "{$row['sub.sub1']}{$row['res.sub1']}";
What to print for sub table elements sub1,sub2,sub3 etc..
The code is working in SQL Query box !

Comment: You got rid of the aliases. It doesn't work without the aliases because you have named the columns identically. You can't say `select *` but instead have to say `SELECT sub.batname, sub.sub1 AS subsub1, sub.sub2 AS subsub2, ...`

Comment: The table res has around 45 columns...Its very untidy to write every column name and also not easy to check for errors in it... Is there any method to do so ??

Answer (score 0):

I just that inner join in your sql query should do it. Somethink like:

```
SELECT * FROM res r INNER JOIN sub s ON r.id = s.id WHERE regno LIKE '1DU12CS100';
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question... The SNo is just for deleting or editing the row... I tried your code and It is not working...what I want is when someone enters 1DU12CS100 then subjects are fetched from sub table where batname is 1DU12CS and results are fetched from res table where regno is 1DU12CS100...

Answer (score 0):

This only looks like the beginning (there's too much to do here) but for starters, you can modify your SQL query at the beginning to something like this, since batname appears to exist as the beginning of all regno variables

```
$sql = "SELECT regno as batname FROM myresult WHERE regno LIKE '{$regno}%'";
```

Then you could turn this into a variable such as `$batname = $row['batname']`

and then you can use `$batname` as a method of linking the data between the tables.  However, you are going to need to do a bit more, as there are some exact strings which exist that mean something.  so you will need to identify specific strings at certain places within `$batname` to identify their meaning.   This will have to be broken apart itself.   It be a good idea to create a new table that identifies the subject names to match the strings that created off of this.

In other words, your script is really just a beginning.  Once you have a way of identifying each element within a string (again a lookup table would make your life a lot easier), you will be able to start working on your php scripting.

Here's an example of a lookup table you could use

```
    code    name
    ---     ----
    CS      Computer Science
```

etc (it is hard for me to tell what is going on with those codes, but I take you know what they all mean).   You should probably pull this data for every piece that means something.

Comment: Thank you for your help and teaching what should be done in this regards... But I am very new to this so I can not do it by my own or I don't have idea how to implement this in database... My main aim now is, when someone enters 1DU12CS100 then subjects are fetched from sub table where batname is 1DU12CS and results are fetched from res table where regno is 1DU12CS100 and result should be displayed in php form... Please help me with the code ....